Alternative proofs of lower bound for Willmore-type energy
TL;DR: Are there any known alternative proofs to the proof given below for $(\ast)$? These could be in particular cases of $n$ or under geometric assumptions on $M$ (such as convexity).

Let $M^n$ be a closed embedded $C^2$ hypersurface of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Suppose that $\kappa_i = \kappa_i(x)$, $i=1,\dots , n$ are the principle curvatures of $M$ at $x\in M$, $\mathrm H = \frac{\kappa_1+\cdots \kappa_n}n$ is the mean curvature of $M$, $K=\kappa_1\cdots \kappa_n$ is the Gaussian curvature, and $\nu:M\to \mathbb S^n$ be the Guass map.
Consider the Willmore-type energy given by $$ \mathcal W(M)=\| \mathrm H \|_{L^n(M)}^n = \int_M \vert \mathrm H \vert^n . $$ It is well-known that $\mathcal W$ satisfies the lower bound $$\tag{$\ast$}\mathcal W(M) \geq \mathcal W(\mathbb S^n) $$ with equality if and only if $M$ is a sphere. (In the literature, it is common to see only the case $n=2$ when $\mathcal W$ is the Willmore energy, but I'm interested in the more general case.) The standard proof (see for example the original paper of Willmore [4] or this article by Topping [3]) goes as follows: let $\Gamma_M$ denote the outer contact set of $M$, that is, $$ \Gamma_M := \{ x\in M \text{ s.t. } M \text{ lies on one side of } T_xM\}.$$ At each point $x\in \Gamma_M$, we have $\kappa_i\geq 0$ for all $i=1,\dots, n$, $$\vert \mathrm H(x) \vert^n =\mathrm H^n(x) \geq K(x)  $$ by the AM-GM inequality. Then $K=\det (d\nu)$, so the area formula implies that $$ \mathcal W(M)\geq \int_{\Gamma_M}\vert \mathrm H \vert^n  \geq \int_{\Gamma_M}K  \geq \vert \nu(\Gamma_M) \vert . $$ Since $\nu(\Gamma_M)=\mathbb S^n$, we obtain $$\mathcal W(M)\geq \vert \mathbb S^n\vert = \mathcal W(\mathbb S^n) .$$ Moreover, equality holds if and only if $M$ is umbilical at every point which is equivalent to $M$ being a sphere.

I'm interested in alternative proofs for $(\ast)$. For example, a more "brutal" geometric measure theory approach could be

Prove $\mathcal W$ has a global minimiser (by the direct method or otherwise). This is done in  [1] by Simon when $n=2$, for example.
Prove the global minimiser of $\mathcal W$ is unique (up to isometries of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$).
Prove that the unique global of minimiser of $\mathcal W$ must be $\mathbb S^n$. (I think for $n=2$ this could be done via the conformal invariance of $\mathcal W$, but $\mathcal W$ is not conformally invariant for general $n$)

I also thought that there could be alternative proofs of $(\ast)$ in the case $M=\partial K$ for a convex body $K \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ (hence, the convex geometry tag) since $\mathcal W$ seems to have a close relationship with quermassintegrals. I could find papers that mention this (see [2]), but no explicit proofs.

[1] Simon, Leon, Existence of surfaces minimizing the Willmore functional, Commun. Anal. Geom. 1, No. 2, 281-326 (1993). ZBL0848.58012.
[2] Tatarko, Kateryna; Werner, Elisabeth M., A Steiner formula in the (L_p) Brunn Minkowski theory, Adv. Math. 355, Article ID 106772, 27 p. (2019). ZBL1423.52009.
[3] Topping, Peter, Towards the Willmore conjecture, Calc. Var. Partial Differ. Equ. 11, No. 4, 361-393 (2000). ZBL1058.53060.[3]
[4] Willmore, T. J., Note on embedded surfaces, An. Sti. Univ. Al. I. Cuza Iasi, N. Ser., Sect. Ia 11B, 493-496 (1965). ZBL0171.20001.
